# Looking for local crashlog when device was tethered to Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, stack-trace, crash-log

Question:

When iOS device is tethered to Xcode and crashed after building (app loaded in, was not a crash ON build), where is the crash log saved to?

Here's my predicament with some context:

I pulled a user's crashlog of EXC_BAD_ACCESS for my app. I symbolicated and I've narrowed it down to get a rough idea but now I'm trying to re-create the issue via building in Xcode to my iOS device (not simulator). Normally the app does not crash on load in (this crash isn't easy to replicate) but I've been able to have the app crash consistently with Address Sanitizer enabled, and it always crashed and points to a line in a thread with an men address -- not anything I don't already have from previous debugging.

However, one time I had a crash occur where it highlighted what func was called as well as every func called in the stack trace and what file this was all occurring in. In haste I hit build again in Xcode before I saved the output however... and now I cannot replicate.

The crashlog wasn't saved locally to my iOS device as I was still tethered to Xcode, and I checked ~Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice but that did not contain them either.

I need find where Xcode would've saved these logs on my mac (if it did at all)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically all the crash dumps are stored in Settings -> Privacy -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostics & Usage Data

Scroll down the list and find the crash file with your app name.

This link might be helpful - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1747/_index.html